# Xcode 7 Git can’t find remote repositories

Tags: ios, xcode, git, xcode7

I could push & pull this repository without any problems on Xcode 6.X, but it doesn’t work on Xcode 7.

The setting is the same as Xcode 6.X. I tried to enter Username and Passphrase just for confirmation, but seems like no meaning. I used the right SSH Keys as Authentication, but the preferences say “The remote repository could not be found.”

[image]

Checking out a new repository, that have been never used on Xcode 6.X ,also had the same issue on Xcode 7.0 and higher.

[image]

I’d like to know if anyone has any solutions for this problem.

Comment: seems like this issue has not been solved yet on Xcode 7.1.

Comment: Xcode 7.2 also has the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

"could not be found" is also the error message you see when you access a repo you don't own (instead of a "permission denied")

For security reason, one does not confirm or deny the existence of a repo, one simply state "it cannot find it".

So make sure the repo exists, that your are the owner and that your public key is registered to your account.

Since that issue seems limited to XCode7, [it was reported before](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13102), and could be linked to a **[cipher issue](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/26074)** (XCode7 refusing to establish a connection with an sshd working with a cipher too weak)

Comment: Thx, but I've already confirmed all of your advise.  As I said it works fine Xcode 6.X, even by using the command line tools.

Comment: @cafedeichi the very same repo, with the very same ssh keys, is working in XCode6?

Comment: @cafedeichi are you using the XCode7 with the same user as the one for XCode6?

Comment: Yes. btw not only me but my co-workers (iOS Developer team) in my office  have the same issue.

Comment: @cafedeichi with *all* the repo or only this one?

Comment: Al the repo has the same issue.

Comment: Thx VonC :) I knew the report on the forums, but seems like a little bit updated. (When i saw the report, no answer for it.) Anyway i could confirm this issue is not only for me. Hoping Apple fixes it soon.

Comment: @cafedeichi in the meantime, check your cipher on the server side: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89084/7490

Comment: Okay, i'm gonna try it.

Answer (score 0):

I have an easy solution if your remote is set and suddenly when you can't pull because of "no remote repository found" message. Go to terminal. Open your project folder. do

```
git pull origin v6.2
```

If you have commits that were not made, you might have to:

```
git reset --hard
git commit -m "Commit Message"
```

After you pull it one, you will be able to pull more with no problem from Xcode.